# save string value in android using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I want to save a string value in android activity using `SharedPreferences`.

This is my `SearchUserAdapter` class : here only passing the search people user id :

```
final String searchuserid = Order.get(SearchProfile.TAG_USER_ID);
    username_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(activity,
                    SearchProfile.class);
            in.putExtra("UserId", searchuserid);
            activity.startActivity(in);
        }
    });
     return vi;
}
```

In this SearchProfile.class:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
userid = i.getStringExtra("UserId");
SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(M_SPF_NAME,
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
loginPreferences.edit().putString(M_USERNAME, userid).commit();
```

Here if I have reloaded the `SearchPorile` activity many times means that time also need to get the same user id when selecting the another user id from that `SearchUserAdapter` class. How can I save this value ? Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: You just need to saved value on `Preferences` in Activity `onPause()` and load it on Activity `onResume()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save Shared Preference:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Get Shred Preference:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName", "YourName");
```

Answer (score 1):

I can propose you a different way. 
First, you prepare a class for shared preference which contain :

```
public static void put(Context context, String key, String value) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(key, value);
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Second, use this where you need and store data. For your purpose, you can call and use this on your adapter(Intent will not be required in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Userinfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("Key", "Yourvalue");
editor.putString("Key", "Yourvalue");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Give some explanation with code so new future user can understand easily.